# Export to csv/excel from kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, export-to-csv, kibana-4

I am building a proof of concept using Elasticsearch Logstash and Kibana for one of my projects. I have the dashboard with the graphs working without any issue. One of the requirements for my project is the ability to download the file(csv/excel). 
In kibana the only option i saw for downloading the file is by clicking on edit button on the visualization created. Is it possible to add a link on the dashboard that would allow users to download the file without going into the edit mode. And secondly I would like to disable/hide the edit mode for anyone other than me who views the dashboard.
Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892560/is-there-any-way-in-elasticsearch-to-get-results-as-csv-file-in-curl-api) might be useful.

Comment: how can I add `export` **CSV** functionality in my custom `plugin`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I totally missed the export button at the bottom of each visualization.
As for read only access...Shield from Elasticsearch might be worth exploring.

Comment: ya..i think kibana has the worst UX ever...i am spending hours on finding a way and I am thinking of wiriting a script to scroll ES and download it my self

Answer (score 47):

To export data to csv/excel from Kibana follow the following steps:-

1. Click on Visualize Tab & select a visualization (if created). If not created create a visualziation.
2. Click on caret symbol (^) which is present at the bottom of the visualization.
3. Then you will get an option of Export:Raw Formatted as the bottom of the page.

Please find below attached image showing Export option after clicking on caret symbol.

[image: Please find below attached image showing Export option after clicking on caret symbol.]

Comment: Do we option to export all search result data?

Comment: It will export all the search result data. If you download by clicking on Raw or Formatted, then all the search result will be downloaded.

Comment: I tried it but it's not downloading all the data. I am debugging it more else I will asked separate question :)  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Added new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653992/can-we-export-all-search-result-data-in-kibana)

Comment: I don't think its possible to export to csv/excel (or other form of tabular structure) even with Kibana Visualize and Dashboard.

Comment: This approach allows me to save just aggregated data (e.g. count of matched records).

Answer (score 47):

FYI : How to download data in CSV from Kibana:

In Kibana-->
1.  Go to 'Discover' in left side

2. Select Index Field (based on your dashboard data)
   (*** In case if you are not sure which index to select-->go to management tab-->Saved Objects-->Dashboard-->select dashboard name-->scroll down to JSON-->you will see the Index name )
3. left side you see all the variables available in the data-->click over the variable name that you want to have in csv-->click add-->this variable will be added on the right side of the columns avaliable
4. Top right section of the kibana-->there is the time filter-->click
   -->select the duration for which you want the csv
5. Top upper right -->Reporting-->save this time/variable selection with a new report-->click generate CSV
6. Go to 'Management' in left side--> 'Reporting'-->download your csv

Comment: @kleptog X-Pack is not required for this.

Comment: "From version 5.0 onward, Reporting is part of X-Pack. For more information, see Reporting from Kibana in the X-Pack Reference." see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/reporting/current/getting-started.html)

Comment: Reporting also needs to be enabled, see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.5/reporting-settings-kb.html

Comment: In Kibana 7.1 I do not see any "Reporting" link and not able to find any download option. Can anyone help with this? I am using AWS Elasticsearch

Comment: @rupsray AWS ES is operating in "Open Source" tier of elastic subscription model. CSV reports are in Basic (free) tier. Thus, it's not enabled. https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

Comment: how to implement this export functionality using api

Answer (score 19):

In Kibana 6.5, you can generate CSV under the Share Tab -> CSV Reports.

The request will be queued. Once the CSV is generated, it will be available for download under Management -> Reporting

Comment: Do I need to install X-Pack to do that?

Comment: I dont believe so

Comment: @OksanaB yes you need X-Pack. It's still free though, but it's not available in non-elastic-hosted solutions, e.g. AWS.