# Calculate session duration in Kibana

Tags: session, statistics, kibana, fluentd

With Kibana I have managed to visualize continious requests in a linear chart by:

- using a line chart
- Y-axis: Aggregation: `Count`
- X-axis: Date Histogram with field `@timestamp`
- Split Lines: Sub Aggregation: `Terms` Field `IP address`

Now I would like to get the average, minimum and maximum session duration out of this. Is this possible, I haven't quite figured out the right approach to take it from here.

[image]

Comment: Consider exporting to excel/csv (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792146/export-to-csv-excel-from-kibana), then do your statistical manipulations with MS Excel or R or with any preferred statistical tool. You can then import data back into your local your local elasticsearch instance (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/3.0/import-some-data.html) and perform new visualizations with Kibana.

Comment: Do you expect to see those additional stats in the same chart or are you ok to visualize them in another chart on your dashboard?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create dashboard to see all this data on one screen.

1. Save this visualization
2. Change Y-axis aggregation type to "Average"
3. Save this visualization with another name
4. Change Y-axis aggregation type to "Minimum"
5. Save this visualization with another name
6. Change Y-axis aggregation type to "Maximum"
7. Save this visualization with another name
8. Create Dashboard with all saved visualizations.