# Can we export all search result data in Kibana?

Tags: kibana

I am trying to export all search result data in Kibana 5. But it's only exporting count of the result. Is there any way to export all data in CSV format 
in Kibana?

Tried so far

1. Clicked on symbol (^) at the bottom of search result
   visualization.
2. Tried with "Raw" and "Formatted" option both.
3. Data is exporting in CSV format (attached image below) but it's
   displaying total count of the search result. But it should export all 65001 result.

[image]

**Getting Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 14):

This is a very longstanding feature request (going back to 2014) with Kibana; see [their issue tracker](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1992). For whatever reasons they seem to be having trouble with implementing it.

If you only need a subset of your fields exported, a workaround is to create a visualization of the fields that you need and export using the buttons in the visualization section; these work as you would expect. The downside to this is that if you need very many fields you will end up with complex and/or multiple visualizations.

If you don't mind installing another thing, there is a Kibana fork called [Kibi](https://siren.solutions/kibi/) which claims to support this, among other useful things. I can't say for sure, as it doesn't run easily for me on the remote ES cluster I am working with right now, but you may have better luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try `Kibi` :)

Comment: @Roopendra Great, I hope it works for you! Please do comment on your results; I'd like to know how this works. I have my csv exporting needs mostly met right now through direct queries to Elasticsearch, but some of the other Kibi features (joins across indices, SQL interoperability) are interesting to me as well. If it works for you I may be motivated to try a bit harder to get it running...   ;-)

Comment: @jkf, Could you explain - how to "create a visualization of the fields that you need and export using the buttons in the visualization section"

Answer (score 0):

You can export to very primitive csv or xls format then you can use browser plugin for exporting table into csv / xls.

You can use firefox/chrome plugins.

For Firefox I used [Table to Excel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/table-to-excel/) .

For Chrome I used [Excel / CSV Generator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/excelcsv-generator/ppeejofkpebeikjaalhlmlmhldkhbgih)

Another simple way to upgrade ELK stack 6.3+

Single click export of Kibana search results to CSV files (Free in X-Pack Basic)

Comment: I dont see how to do that ... and Im in Kibana 6.7

Answer (score -2):

For me it shows on management tab. [image]