# How can I export data from ElasticSearch 6.3.2

Tags: elasticsearch, export, kibana

I tries to export data from "Discover" to CSV with no luck.
I read in Google version 6 supports exporting, but only example I saw was either using ES 6.5 or "Visualize" screen.

I also tried to export the data using "Dev tools" - with no luck.

Currently i have access to the ES instance (port 9200), is there any way to export data using the CMD?

My goal is to copy some data from one Index to another on the same ES.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply using the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/docs-reindex.html)?

Comment: Thanks!
I wasn't familiar with reindex :)

Answer (score 0):

As @val mentioned in the comment, you can use reindex API. in that API you can specify a query, with filters that would suite only the data you want to move to the new index.

See full info here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

More reference on exporting:
[Export to csv/excel from kibana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792146/export-to-csv-excel-from-kibana)

Comment: Thanks :)
Indeed @val's response was helpful 
Regards the "Export to csv/excel from Kibana" link, I don't won't to export from visualize since it is aggregated data

Comment: if you would like to export data which is the result of an aggregation and not raw data: either run the agg with big enough size, or if size is too big you can run a composite aggregation, collect the results and index them back: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html