# How can I export all 8304 hits?

Tags: kibana, logz.io

We use `logz.io/#/dashboard/kibana` to monitor our logs. My filter results in 8304 hits. I want to export them as a CSV for further analysis. When I click on `export` (next to New, Save, Open, Share, and Auto-refresh) I only get the first 500 hits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Upd**. According to response to a [similar question](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/why-we-need-to-scroll-to-see-next-records-in-discover-table-of-kibana/38844/7), the increasing the value of [`discover:sampleSize`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html) option will help here: downloaded CSVs should contain more rows.

However, in his response the member of Elastic team suggests pulling required data by querying Elasticsearch directly should be preferred.

---

Try exporting from Elasticsearch directly.

Consider example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22945812/80851) to "[Is there any way in Elasticsearch to get results as CSV file in curl api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892560/is-there-any-way-in-elasticsearch-to-get-results-as-csv-file-in-curl-api)" question.

Alternatively, use a tool called [`elasticsearch-dump`](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump). Getting a `csv` with logs becomes a two steps process:

1. First, dump contents of desired index/query into a `json` file:

   ```
   elasticdump \
     --input=http://production.es.com:9200/my_index \
     --output=query.json \
     --searchBody='{"query":{"term":{"username": "admin"}}}'
   ```
2. Turn `json` file into `csv` file (more on this in "[Export JSON to CSV with Headers using JQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453349/30894)") using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command line utility.

Alternatively, check out [this script](https://github.com/maozza/helpers-scripts/blob/master/elasticsearch2csv.py) to dump ES index in `csv` format.

Comment: Ok. Surprised though that since the export button exists in the UI, I can not specify that I want all instead of the first 500.

Comment: @LeeviL seems like it's possible to download the desired CSV by adjusting a config value in Kibana. I've updated the answer.