# How to export data from kibana(ELK stack) as CSV from API calls?

Tags: api, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I have already export data from kibana(ELK stack) as in JSON file format by API calls.But the requirement to get enhanced data table's data as in CSV format through API calls.Is there a way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892560/is-there-any-way-in-elasticsearch-to-get-results-as-csv-file-in-curl-api).

Short answer: **No**.  This is no API provided to get the data as CSV.  You need to do the data conversion yourself.

Comment: is it possible now?